# Merge copy values to dup ID?

Tags: merge, spss

I want to merge two files using a shared ID variable.

Vars in file 1 (mother):
IDofMother  Age Education

Vars in file 2 (child):
IDofMother (matches ID in file 1), Sex, Education, Child's name, Child's age.

Problem is that if a mother has more than one child, the same mothers ID will appear for each child in file 2, but SPSS does not duplicate values of cases associated with same IDofmother (Sex, Education, Child's name, Child's age) in file 2 - second and subsequent values of cases for the same IDofmother appear as missing values.

Any way I can force SPSS to copy the the second subsequent values for the same IDofmother at file 1?

I tried Merge files -> Add variables -> Match cases on key variables - Both files provide cases, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear to me from your question, but I assume you want to add columns to file2 [child] from file1 [mother] -- namely, mother's age and mother's education.

You can use `MATCH FILES` to do that, but you should rename your variables first to make sure the two files only share variable names when variables refer to the same thing. Also, sort by ID (required for `MATCH FILES`).

For instance, in file1 [mother] you might use:

```
RENAME VARIABLES
 (ID=IDofMother)
 (Age=AgeOfMother)
 (Education=EducationOfMother) .
SORT CASES BY IDofMother .
SAVE OUTFILE='mother.sav' .
```

and in file2 [child]:

```
RENAME VARIABLES
 (Sex=SexOfChild)
 (Education=EducationOfChild) .
SORT CASES BY IDofMother .
SAVE OUTFILE='child.sav' .
```

From there:

```
MATCH FILES FILE='child.sav' /* file2 */
 /TABLE='mother.sav' /* file1 */
 /BY IDofMother .
EXE .
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution **offered by @user45392** is the right way to go, this is the same just a bit shorter (and without saving extra files to disk)

```
get file='path\mothers data.sav'.
sort cases by ID.
dataset name mother.

get file='path\children data.sav'.
sort cases by IDofmother.
dataset name child.

MATCH FILES FILE=child /rename (sex Education=sexChl EducationChl)
 /TABLE='mother.sav' /rename (ID Age Education=IDofMother AgeMoth EducationMoth)
 /BY IDofMother .
EXE .
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your instant response but probably I was not clear. I have already done what it is described by @user45392. There are no issues with the name of the variables or the sorting through a certain ID. The problem is that SPSS does not duplicate the mother's Age and Education for each of the children in the merged file - second and subsequent appear as missing values.

Comment: Then forget about all the renaming - just make sure both files are sorted by  "IDofMother " and run: `MATCH FILES /FILE=child /TABLE='mother.sav' /BY IDofMother .`

Comment: Thank you for this, however, nothing new happened. Here, I describe more clearly the problem. Problem is that if a mother has more than one child, the same mothers ID will appear for each child in file 2, but SPSS does not duplicate values of cases associated with same IDofmother (Sex, Education, Child's name, Child's age) in file 2 - second and subsequent values of cases for the same IDofmother appear as missing values.

Comment: `match files` is supposed to work exactly as you describe. possibly some other factor is at play here - if you could post (as an edit to your original question) a sample of your data and the syntax you are using, maybe we could pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Hello, I edited the original post. The syntax I am using is very much similar to the ones proposed.

Comment: Hello, the issue has not yet resolved. The problem is that for the problem is that SPSS does not duplicate the mother's Age and Education for each of the children in the merged file - second and subsequent appear as missing values.  In other words, Problem is that if a mother has more than one child, the same mothers ID will appear for each child in file 2, but SPSS does not duplicate values of cases associated with same IDofmother (Sex, Education, Child's name, Child's age) in file 2 - second and subsequent values of cases for the same IDofmother appear as missing values.

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: I'd really like to help but you're ignoring my requests above for additional information. The situation you are describing is not possible, so either your data is not like you described, or you are not using the syntax as we suggested. In order to help you need to add to your post some sample data and the actual syntax you have been using so we can understand what the problem is